# Como ejecutar una CURL con metodo POST

Tags: php, api, php7, curl

Tengo un problema al intentar ejecutar una CURL pasando parámetros con el método POST, la CURL que quiero ejecutar es esta:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_ENV' \
  -d '{
    "token":"b3a7dbec3eb0d71798c4f19fec445795",
    "installments":1,
    "transaction_amount":58.80,
    "description":"Point Mini a maquininha que dá o dinheiro de suas vendas na hora",
    "payment_method_id":"visa",
    "payer":{
    "email":"test_user_123456@testuser.com"

    }
```

Estos son los datos minimos que Mercado Pago me pide para poder hacer un registro de un pago nuevo,
estoy intentando ejecutar esta consulta desde PHP, estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```
<?php

  $curl = curl_init();
  $token = "5ad1c4126a25bbabc068961e69e7d5ce";
  $installments = 1;
  $transaction_amount = 100;
  $description = "Pago desde cURL";
  $payment_method_id = "master";
  $payer = array(
  "email" => "test_user_77251776@testuser.com"
  );

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments?access_token=TEST-1234-56789-101112-456789');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"transaction_amount\" : \"$transaction_amount\",
                                           \"token\" : \"$token\",
                                           \"description\" : \"$description\",
                                           \"installments\" : \"$installments\",
                                           \"payment_method_id\" : \"$payment_method_id\",
                                           \"payer\" : \"$payer\"}");
  $data = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  echo $data;

?>
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar en postman me da los siguientes dos errores:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp20\htdocs\Apoya pagos\Curl\pago_curl.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
{
    "message": "transaction_amount attribute must be numeric",
    "error": "bad_request",
    "status": 400,
    "cause": [
        {
            "code": 4003,
            "description": "transaction_amount attribute must be numeric",
            "data": null
        }
    ]
}
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal al enviar mi campo payer como un arreglo y tampoco entiendo por que me dice que transaction_amount debe ser numérico cuando lo estoy pasando como numero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu codigo PHP tienes

```
{\"transaction_amount\" : \"$transaction_amount\"
```

que resulta en

```
{"transaction_amount" : "100"
```

mientras en CURL original esta

```
    "transaction_amount":58.80,
```

sin comillas alrededor del número.

Pueden haber otros errores, es un el que te dice el servidor: `transaction_amount attribute must be numeric`, espera un numero y recibe una cadena.

Tambien te recomiendo que formes JSON con una función especial, será más cómodo y con menos errores

```
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array(
   "transaction_amount" => $transaction_amount,
   "token" => $token,
 )))
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, muchas gracias, no note las comillas. muchas gracias por tu ayuda